# Converting NSNumber to NSInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to determine what a value is in an array and then implement changes on the array, but I can't access the array in the first place...

```
NSNumber *row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:recognizer.view.tag];
    NSInteger *newRow = [row integerValue];
    NSInteger *index = [selectedItems indexOfObject:row];//0=Not selected 1=selected;
    NSLog(@"%@ & ",row);
    if (index == 0) {
        [selectedItems removeObjectAtIndex:newRow];
        [selectedItems insertObject:@"1" atIndex: newRow];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [selectedItems removeObjectAtIndex: newRow];
        [selectedItems insertObject:@"0" atIndex: newRow];;
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
```

As you can see I'm trying to get information from the row variable, which is a NSNumber and find the value of the array with the index variable. Also I declared this in my onload()...

```
selectedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 0, 0, 0, nil];
```

The problem is that I get all of these warnings saying...

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') with an expression of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int');
```

Whenever I use the varaibles row or newRow. As you can see newRow is just row as an integer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

NSInteger is just a typedef for `int` so it's not an object type, it's a scalar, you don't have to declare it as a pointer type. Use

```
NSInteger newRow = [row integerValue];
```

instead.

Comment: +1. Just want to add that even though NSInteger is just a typedef for int, it's more useful than just an int because it will accomodate for 32-bit/64-bit architectures on its own.

Comment: If I remove the pointer for newRow and index, I get no warnings, but when I run my application I get an error when I run this code...  NSLog(@"%@ & %@",newRow, index); The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Better to think of it as a typedef for `long` (even when it isn't.) Its size differs depending on the target architecture.

Comment: @Joe Burnett - yes, because `%@` is for objects. Use `%d` instead. @Jonathan Grynspan: you are right.

Answer (score 2):

NSInteger is a primitive, not an object type.  Collections such as arrays can only contain objects, such as NSNumber.

You can get the primitive value from an NSNumber using methods such a `-integerValue`.  Note that you don't normally want to make an NSInteger pointer (NSInteger*), you just want an NSInteger.

There's also no point in taking `recognizer.view.tag`, making an NSNumber from that, then calling `-integerValue` on that NSNumber.  Just use `recognizer.view.tag` directly as the integer value.  (You can still assign it to a local variable for quick access.)

Comment: The "%@" format specifier in an NSLog call expects its argument to be an object pointer.  To log an integer, use "%d".